# Truth of statements about numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers, integers

Given the following statements:

1. $\forall\, x,y \in \Bbb Q \quad \exists\, z \in \Bbb Q $ $\;$ $ : \left(x<z<y\right) \vee \left(x>z>y\right)$.
2. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb R \quad \exists\,y\in \Bbb R : y^2= x$
3. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb R^+ \quad \exists\,y\in \Bbb R : y^2= x$
4. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb Z : | x | > 0$
5. $\forall\, x,y \in \Bbb Q : \left(x<y \rightarrow \exists\, z \in \Bbb Q: x<z<y \right)$
6. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb N \quad \exists\, y \in \Bbb N : x>y$
7. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb R \quad \exists\, y \in \Bbb R : y^2=|x|$
8. $\forall \, x \in \Bbb Z \quad \exists\, y \in \Bbb Z: x \lt y \lt x+1 $
9. $\exists\,x \in \Bbb N \quad \forall\, y \in \Bbb N : x\le y$
10. $\forall \, x,y \in \Bbb N \quad \exists \, z \in \Bbb N: x+z=y$
11. $\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\quad\exists\,y\in\Bbb R:x\lt y \lt x+1$
12. $\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb Q\quad\exists\,x\in\Bbb Q:ax=b$
13. $\forall\,x\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,y\in\Bbb Z : x\gt y$
14. $\forall\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,z\in\Bbb Z:x+z=y$
15. $\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,x\in\Bbb Z:ax=b$
16. $\forall\,m\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,q\in\Bbb Q:m\lt q\lt m+1$

list which are true.

Only $2,6$ and $8$ are false, correct?

Comment: No, there are others that are false. For instance, 1 is false. Ex: let x=1, y=2. Then there is no z satisfying the conditions.

Comment: 4. is false when x=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete list of true statements is:

3)  $\forall \, x \in \Bbb R^+ \quad \exists\,y\in \Bbb R : y^2= x$

5) $\forall\, x,y \in \Bbb Q : \left(x<y \rightarrow \exists\, z \in \Bbb Q: x<z<y \right)$

7) $\forall \, x \in \Bbb R \quad \exists\, y \in \Bbb R : y^2=|x|$

9)  $\exists\,x \in \Bbb N \quad \forall\, y \in \Bbb N : x\le y$

11) $\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\quad\exists\,y\in\Bbb R:x\lt y \lt x+1$

13) $\forall\,x\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,y\in\Bbb Z : x\gt y$

14.) $\forall\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,z\in\Bbb Z:x+z=y$

16) $\forall\,m\in\Bbb Z\quad\exists\,q\in\Bbb Q:m\lt q\lt m+1$

For each the others (that are not true), you need only find a single counterexample in which the statement is false: $\color{red}{1, 2,4,6,8,10, 12, 15}$

Note that $1)$ is false whenever $x = y$.  It would be true, however, if we have $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb Q((x\neq y) \rightarrow \exists z \in \mathbb Q (x\lt z \lt y)\lor (x\gt z\gt y))$$

$(12)$ is false, if we take $a = 0, b= 2$, e.g., but is true if we state 
12) $\forall\,a,b\in\Bbb Q((a\neq 0)\rightarrow\exists\,x\in\Bbb Q(ax=b))$

Comment: I just realized i goofed up when I transcribed my list, statement $1.$ should have been about rational numbers such that $\forall\, x,y \in \Bbb Q \quad \exists\, z \in \Bbb Q $ $\;$ $ : \left(x<z<y\right) \vee \left(x>z>y\right)$ wihch is why I said $1.$ was true, can I add it to your answer?

Comment: Yes, in the case of $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb Q(\exists z\in Q: (x\lt z\lt y)\lor (x\gt z\gt y))$$  is indeed true (for any $x, y, \in \mathbb Q).$ Just put $z = \frac {x+y}{2}$,

Comment: Statement 1. as phrased is still false. Take $x=y$

Comment: Aha...Your right, @Max

Comment: So 1 and 12 should be added to your list

Comment: @amWhy: So statements involving quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ are always proved or disproved by finding counterexamples?

Comment: Typically , quantified statements are *disproved* when a counter-example exists.  In true cases, you can often justify why true, e.g. $(3)$: For every $x\in \mathbb R$, there exists $y = \sqrt x$, such that $y^2= x$....

Comment: That should be (in my last comment)  " For every x \in \mathbb R^+, there exists y (namely, $y = \sqrt x,) $ such that $y^2 = x$"

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is false for x=3 and y=4 there doesn't exist a z. 
Number 4 as well for x=0.  
Number 10 for x=3 and y=2 there doesn't exist a z. 
Number 15 take a=2 and b=1 there doesn't exist x.

Comment: It might also be good to confirm or disconfirm the OP's findings.

Answer (score 0):

1. False. Let $x:=0$ and $y:=0$.
2. False. Let $x:=-1$.
3. True. Let $y:=\sqrt{x}$.
4. False. Let $x:=0$.
5. True. Let $z:=\frac{x+y}{2}$.
6. False. Let $x:=0$.
7. True. Let $y:=\sqrt{|x|}$.
8. False. Let $x:=0$.
9. True. Let $x:=0$.
10. False. Let $x:=1$ and $y:=0$.
11. True. Let $y:=x+\frac{1}{2}$.
12. False. Let $a:=0$ and $b:=1$.
13. True. Let $y:=x-1$.
14. True. Let $z:=y-x$.
15. False. Let $a:=0$ and $b:=1$.
16. True. Let $q:=m+\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

1 isn't true as I've pointed out in the comments, as $x=y$ gives a counterexample; 
2 of course isn't true; 
3 is true; 
4 is obviously wrong; 
5 is the correct version of 1, it's true; 
6 is obviously wrong; 
7 is true; 
8 is wrong; 
9 is true; 
10 is wrong; 
11 is right; 
12 is wrong, take $a=0, b \neq 0$; 
13 is true; 
14 is true; 
15 is wrong, there are the counterexamples of 12, and even more; 
16 is true; 
So the list of false statements is more than OP thought, it's actually 1, 2, 4, 6,8,10,12,15